# Regarding cssparser

Tags: java, css

Friends I am using cssparser for parsing my CSS. My code is like this:

```
public static Map<String, CSSStyleRule> parseCSS1() throws IOException {
    Map<String, CSSStyleRule> rules = new LinkedHashMap<String, CSSStyleRule>();

    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new FileReader("C:\\COMPUTERS.css"));
    CSSStyleSheet styleSheet = new CSSOMParser().parseStyleSheet(inputSource, null, null);

    CSSRuleList ruleList = styleSheet.getCssRules();
    for (int i = 0; i < ruleList.getLength(); i++) {
        CSSRule rule = ruleList.item(i);
        if (rule.getType() == CSSRule.STYLE_RULE) {
            CSSStyleRule styleRule = (CSSStyleRule) rule;
            rules.put(styleRule.getSelectorText(), styleRule);
        }
    }

    return rules;
}
```

Now after parsing when I try to print the value in CSS (`rules.getvalues()`) it gives this result:

```
BODY { font-family: monospace; 
    color: black; 
    font-size: medium; 
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal; 
    background-color: rgb(255, 182, 193);
    background-image: url(images/COMPUTERSbody_computers.gif);
    border: no }
```

In the last line there is no semicolon after `border:no` and in the original CSS it is present.

So, should I manually add that semicolon or am I making a mistake?

Also, in the original CSS:

```
background-color: #FFB6C1
```

Is replaced by:

```
background-color: rgb(255, 182, 193);
```

in the parsed output. Is there any way to keep the original as it is?

Answer (score 1):

The last semi-colon in a CSS declaration is not mandatory and is being left out on purpose by the library.